# Ionic2 button click does not work on only one page

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a simple navigation setup between pages. And on one page, on button click event doesn't seem to do anything. Even if I put a simple console.log output just in it, it does not seems like it is triggered at all.

I am quite sure that it is something trivial, but here is my code.
The data passed in is tested to be all ok.

ts file - itemTapped is the problematic function..

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { EliteApi } from '../../shared/shared';
import { TeamHomePage } from '../team-home/team-home';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-game',
  templateUrl: 'game.html'
})
export class GamePage {

  game: any = {};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, 
          public navParams: NavParams,
          public eliteApi: EliteApi) {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.game = this.navParams.data;
  }

  teamTapped(teamId){
    let tourneyData = this.eliteApi.getCurrentTourney();
    let team = tourneyData.teams.find(t => t.id === teamId);
    this.navCtrl.push(TeamHomePage, team);
  }

}
```

html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Game</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h3>Home Team</h3>
  <button ion-button (clicked)="teamTapped(game.team1Id)">{{game.team1}}</button>
</ion-content>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have typo in this line where you declared button. Instead of clicked you should write click. Here is correct button code:

```
<button ion-button (click)="teamTapped(game.team1Id)">{{game.team1}}</button>
```

Comment: tnx, I knew it was something trivial